# How to configure distcc for a text file dependency

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ssh, clang, distcc

I am trying to distribute the build with `distcc` that uses `clang` with sanitizers in the following way:

`clang++-12 -fsanitize-blacklist=/path/to/the/blacklist.txt ...`

So there is a non-`cpp` dependency in the build.

`distcc` currently fails with the following output:

```
remote compilation of <file.cpp> failed, retrying locally
```

And in the temp files retained with

```
export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1 # To see the paths of the tmp files
export DISTCC_SAVE_TEMPS=1 # To preserve tmp files
```

I see the following error:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/to/the/blacklist.txt'`

How to configure `distcc` to copy the non-`cpp` dependency to the remote build machines? Any other thoughts about a workaround?

Environment: I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 client laptop and an Ubuntu 20.04 server machine with an Ubuntu 20.04 `docker` image. The build environment is installed inside the `docker` image. The server has only a public IP, so I had to configure `distcc` to use SSH for connecting from the client to the server.

Comment: Maybe google chromium have solution that they use icecream or goma, see also: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#faster-builds

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the another version of distcc like icecc would helped.

https://github.com/icecc/icecream/commit/a2f0d7507c2fb87096c74582d05cdfc05c6e3e40

distcc is update frequency but the last commit of icecream is in Jun 2020, or maybe something like incredibuild (not sure) may helped too.

Comment: Indeed - Incredibuild will sync all files that are requested by the remotely ran process from the initiator to the remote machine on demand, without the need for any extra configuration from the user side.